# AngularJS - Suggestions for auto generating a factory for accessing a REST API

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, rest, automation

Im getting to grips with AngularJS and Node.js and am building an app which will interact with multiple table within a MYSQL database.

One approach which looks efficient is to use Sequelize for ORM and then [Epilogue](https://github.com/dchester/epilogue) to create the REST endpoints.
The next step would be to wire an Angular Factory into the REST end points and it strikes me that there must be an efficient way to do this.
Ive read [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/) article on using $resource and [this](https://github.com/rayokota/generator-angular-express-sequelize) article on using a Yeoman template to generate the code.

I would be interested to hear what recommendations others have for the autogeneration of an Angular factory for an existing REST API.

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be what I am looking for [StrongLoop](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK)

Point it at a REST API and it will auto generate the Angular $resource elements.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done autogeneration but I like using $http and calling an AJAX/Form controller which then calls the appropriate service/factory as needed.